android Criteria deprecated while using locationManager
In my andorid app, I am obtaining the user's location. But when the user has no GPS on or Network, I am trying to get the last location:
    if (!isGPS && !isNetwork) {
        showSettingsAlert();
        getLastLocation();
    }

private void getLastLocation() {
    try {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if(provider==null) {     progressDialog.cancel();
        showSettingsAlert();     progressDialog.cancel();}
        else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location != null) {updateUI(location);}
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

The problem is, Criteria() is already deprecated. Is there any alternative I can use in my code?
I found something like this:
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(null, false);

But now getBestProvider has null instead of criteria. How to getBestProvider when I can't use Criteria?

Create the location provider client:
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

Now you can get the last location:
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    // do what you want with location object
                }
            }
        });

